# php/mysql - foreign characters

Tags: php, mysql

I am having problems displaying foreign characters (characters with accents like: é à ù ç and so on)

The row in the database is like this:

```
    Name | Datatype | Charset 
title | varchar(255) | utf8_general_ci
```

I store it like this:

```
function inputFilter($var)
{
    $var = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($var)));

    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        $var = stripslashes($var);

    $var = mysql_real_escape_string($var);

    return $var;
}
$title = inputFilter($_POST['title']);
```

and I print it like this:

```
print $getfromdb['title'];
```

This is how it's printed out:

```
PortuguÃªs //Should be: Português
```

I have tried adding:
htmlspecialchars, utf8_decode/encode and htmlentities to the print, although nothing helps!

I've added this to the header:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume you are printing this on a webpage. Is it also encoded as UTF-8?

Comment: It surely is. I've added this to the header: <meta charset="utf-8">

Comment: You likely haven't correctly set the [character set of your database connection](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-connection.html).  See [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/q/279170).

Comment: Note also, for your future reference, that `utf8_general_ci` is a *collation* (used for performing comparisons/sorting) and not a *character set*.  The character set is `utf8`.

Comment: Have you tried:
1) setting the db connection to utf-8 - `mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $conn);`
2) have you specified in the meta `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`
3) is the encoding of your file UTF-8? (*edit: this one is an overkill - nvm this one)

Comment: Furthermore, one should normally perform display-related escaping (such as the call to PHP's `htmlentities()` function) upon display and not upon storage.  Suppose in the future that you wish to use some other output medium: one would have to undo the HTML-specific encoding stored within the database and then apply whatever media-specific encoding is required for the new output.  Far better to store data in a neutral, unescaped form and then perform the requisite escaping after retrieving the data from the database.

Comment: @eithed: It is preferable to use API-specific methods of setting the connection character set (if available - which is not the case with the deprecated mysql extension), or else use `SET NAMES`.

Comment: `$var = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($var)));` - in my eye, this whole line (except of trim), isnt really necessary. i'm not sure but unless your php version is >= 5.4, htmlentities can produce an unexpected output without the encoding argument.

Comment: @eggyal - I'm not assuming anything about the environment (besides that it's PHP/mysql). Whatever libraries the OP is using is his choice, and the code I posted should work irregardless. `SET NAMES` doesn't work as you'd expect it to (or at least, it didn't for me - that's why the setting of all the DB encodings)

Comment: @eithed: As documented under [Connection Character Sets and Collations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-connection.html), "*A `SET NAMES 'charset_name'` statement is equivalent to these three statements: `SET character_set_client = charset_name; SET character_set_results = charset_name; SET character_set_connection = charset_name;`*". Therefore, the only difference with your version is that it does not set `character_set_database` or `character_set_server`, but these affect only DDL statements (they set the default values for new objects) - they do not affect the results of DML statements.

Comment: @eggyal - I've had these sort of issues quite long ago when everything was running different encodings (DB - utf8, table - latin_1, column - utf8/latin_1, adapter - ???, expected output - ISO-8859-2); given command became my silver bullet, even though `SET NAMES` **should** work. Now I use zend + have control on everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to Follow:

Use the meta tag for UTF8.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Set your PHP to use UTF8.

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
mb_http_input('UTF-8');
```

For mysql, you want to convert your table to UTF8.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

Also you can run:

```
 SET NAMES UTF8
```

as the first query after establishing a connection which will convert your DB connection to UTF8.

Comment: Where do I set the mb_ stuff? php.ini?

Comment: Those are PHP functions. (optional) For Eg. mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8') Sets internal character encoding as UTF-8 You can use those in your PHP source.

Answer (score 2):

Include `mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");` right after every connection you make. This will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

`<meta charset="UTF-8">` is HTML 5 (and, BTW, `UTF-8` is uppercase)

Since it looks like your test chain also involves a form (because of the `$_POST`), you must make sure that the UTF-8 charset is set for the form too.

Comment: AFAIK if the server is sending a charset HTTP header, the browser will ignore this *meta* tag. In OP's case, it would be possible that his (misconfigured) server sends a wrong charset.

Comment: @ComFreek: correct. But I would give it a try, since the OP may be using a shared hosting server, and in my opinion a shared hosting server shouldn't make any assumption on the desired charset.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SET NAMES utf8` before you query/insert into the database

```
query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use character encoding as `ISO-8859-1` instead of `UTF-8` as follows:

```
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
```

The characters you are trying to show are **latin** and `UTF-8` i.e. **UNICODE** encoding cannot interpret latin characters.

**[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_charset.asp)**

And in case of mysql you should use `latin1` charset.