# PHP/Notepad++ Mongolian Characters

Tags: php, string, notepad++

Alright I'm pretty sure this is a silly question: I'm working with strings in Mongolian, using PHP, Notepad++, how am I supposed to get my page to display correctly these characters? For example: 'нэвтрэн' (log in)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP and HTML code you must set the encoding. This should hopefully fix the problem!

Refer to this: [php/mysql - foreign characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546792/php-mysql-foreign-characters)

Comment: Yeah that did the trick, actually I thought it was already set. Thank you.