# JSON still showing NULL even after making changes to utf8mb4 - what am I missing?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, utf-8, utf8mb4

In essence, my JSON is printing NULL for fields that contain a special character.

I have read around the subject and followed the duplicate question, as well as other threads, one post in particular highlighted that I need to do the following:

`If you're using mysqli, you can call set_charset():
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');       // object oriented style
mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8mb4');  // procedural style
If you're stuck with plain mysql but happen to be running PHP ≥ 5.2.3, you can call mysql_set_charset.
If the driver does not provide its own mechanism for setting the connection character set, you may have to issue a query to tell MySQL how your application expects data on the connection to be encoded: SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'.`

I have done this as documented in the `openConnection()` function as below in my connection script:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

class MySQLDao{

var $dbhost = null;
var $dbuser = null;
var $dbpass = null;
var $conn = null;
var $dbname = null;
var $result = null;

public function __construct(){
    $this->dbhost = Conn::$dbhost;
    $this->dbuser = Conn::$dbuser;
    $this->dbpass = Conn::$dbpass;
    $this->dbname = Conn::$dbname;
}

public function openConnection()
{

    $this->conn = new mysqli($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $this->dbname);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        echo new Exception("Could not establish connection with database");
mysqli_set_charset($this->conn, "utf8mb4");
}
```

I have been through my database in phpMyAdmin and converted all my collations to ut8mb4_bin.  I have put in the `mysql_set_chars` line as suggested, and I have also changed all of my tables to utf8mb4 through this type of command `ALTER TABLE teams CHANGE name name VARCHAR(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE  utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`

These are my database setting from phpMyAdmin:

> My web server details are
>   Apache
>   Database client version: libmysql - 5.0.77
>   PHP extension: mysqli Documentation
>   PHP version: 5.3.3

Yet none of this has fixed my problem.

My character_set_server is displaying as latin1, could this be the issue?

`+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | latin1             |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | latin1_swedish_ci  |
+--------------------------+--------------------+`

I am at a loss at what else to try.

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but I found this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546792/php-mysql-foreign-characters

Comment: Is the application using a specific encoding intentionally set, or it's just using the default encoding of the involved tools?

Comment: I'm assuming the default tools since I haven't set anything myself.

Comment: I suspect that your data is not utf8-encoded.  Let's see the hex.

Comment: How do I display the hex?

Comment: `echo bin2hex($json);`

Comment: Thanks Rick, how do I use that in conjunction with an array?  My current JSON query is:  `echo json_encode(array('countries' => $countries,'divisions' => $divisions,'teams' => $teams));`

Comment: @RickJames - hex printout -> http://pastebin.com/mtJvCxP7

Comment: Thanks, but... Please isolate a short part of it that contains the characters giving trouble.

Comment: Thanks James i managed to get to the bottom of it.  it was a mixture of my php version being out of date and the way it was calling the mysqli_charset function. Thanks for your help though, appreciated